# Manipulate property and use in sort-object

Tags: powershell, properties, sort-object

I need to modify content in Powershell property `Description` and then use the content in `Sort-Object`, how can this be done ? 
Below is my sample, which is not working:

```
Sort-Object -Property $($_.Description).Split(":")[2].Trimend(")") -Descending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your calculated property expression in `{}`:

```
Sort-Object -Property {$_.Description.Split(":")[2].TrimEnd(")")} -Descending
```